# Nodejs express: How to return Value into outer callback from a inner callback inside a loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi I am new to nodejs and mongoDB. I am not getting the value into outer callback from an inner callback which is in a loop.
I have tried with following code

```
getDoctorsSchedules(req,res){
        console.log("*** All Doctor's Schedule..."); 
        doctorsschedulesRepo.getDoctorsSchedules(req.body,(err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("***All Doctor's Schedule Schedule: " + util.inspect(err));
                res.json({
                    states: null
                });
            } else {
                console.log('*** All Doctor Schedule ok');
                if(data)
                {
                   
                    var reslt;
                    reslt = function(data ,callback){
                        var r = [];
                        for( let i in data)
                        {
                            r[i] = data[i].toObject();
                            //fetch doctors details by doctor's id
                             doctorRepo.getDoctorListbyID(data[i].DoctorID,(err, result)=>{
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log('---- DOCTOR ' + util.inspect(err));
                                    
                                } else {
                                   if(result){
                                    r[i].Doctors = result;
                                    console.log(r[i].Doctors);
                                    callback(r[i].Doctors);
                                   }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                    res.json({"success":true,"data":reslt});
                           
                }
                
                
            }
        });
    }
```

Actually I am trying to fetch data by id from the inner callback, and this ids are populating as a json array into outer callback.

Thank you in advance

Comment: please paste the error and the data that you're receiving

Comment: Not getting any error. I am getting data into inner callback inside the loop. but unable to  access from outer callback

Comment: Can you try promise instead of callback?

Comment: @user2510946 Where are you calling the reslt function? Looks like only a function has been assigned to reslt variable but never called. What are you trying to send back in the data field? Because looks like you have not returned anything from the function

Comment: @user2510946 Also, if you really want to send the data related to the doctors, you should move this line inside the callback
res.json({"success":true,"data":reslt});
Otherwise the desired result will not be sent